# Customized approach to setting the jdbc connection with the birt reporting engine

Tags: birt

We're using birt 2.6.2 reporting to display reports in our tomcat hosted web app.  We have a reporting.rptlibrary file that contains a `<data-sources>` and `<oda-data-source>` xml element.  Subsequently, all of the report designs reference that reporting.rptlibrary.  This is troublesome because everytime I deploy the app, I need to change the reporting.rptlibrary to use the correct jdbc connection info.

Our app is setup so that the connection object is stored in a static field, and the app accesses that field directly during runtime.  Is there a way to configure birt to use the connection object that sits in the static field?

I've seen [this blog post](http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2005/12/using-supplied-connection-with-birt.html), and it seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for, but the post was written in 2005, and it's saying I need to create an eclipse plugin, which doesn't seem right for a web app.

I also see some posts about using connection pooling with birt, but we're not using connection pooling.

I am open minded to upgrading to birt 3.7 if it will help with this issue and won't necessitate a large migration effort.

Answer (score 3):

For reports run from Java code, here is the solution working in 2.6.2 and 3.7.0:

```
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;
import java.sql.Connection
...
IRunAndRenderTask task; //or IRunTask, when run+render invoked separately
Connection connection;
...
Map<String, Object> appContext = task.getAppContext();
appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", connection);
appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnectionCloseAfterUse", false);
task.setAppContext(appContext);
...
task.run()
```

Connection is passed-in to report and replaces/hides all JDBC connections defined in report design.

Comment: It's not hiding the data-source declared in my .rptlibary file.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: It seems that the ones that are failing aren't being run from the java side.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: this connection is still not used (at least when using "dbprofile" data sources) .. I can't understand in which case this tips can work (using BIRT runtime 3.7.2.v20120214-1408 from maven repository).

Answer (score 1):

try this in xml

```
<data-sources>
        <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" name="fitupvisualdatasource" id="365">
            <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>metadataBidiFormatStr</name>
                    <value>ILYNN</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>disabledMetadataBidiFormatStr</name>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>contentBidiFormatStr</name>
                    <value>ILYNN</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>disabledContentBidiFormatStr</name>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>
            <property name="odaDriverClass">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
            <property name="odaURL">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/acctsql_whs</property>
            <property name="odaUser">apoel</property>
            <encrypted-property name="odaPassword" encryptionID="base64">cXdlcnR5</encrypted-property>
        </oda-data-source>
    </data-sources>
```